# If $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, does this imply that $(f_n)$ uniformly converges to $f$ on an interval of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

If a sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to the same function $f$ on all $\mathbb{R}$, does this imply that $(f_n)$ uniformly converges to $f$ on an interval of $\mathbb{R}$?

From what I understand, this should be false. I know from a theorem that if a sequence of functions converges uniformly to a function $f$, $f$ is continuous. However, the converse is false (I think). In other words, the fact that a sequence of functions converges to a continuous function does not guarantee that the sequence of functions is uniformly convergent.

If $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to the same function $f$ on all $\mathbb{R}$, wouldn't that simply mean that the $f$ is continuous? Using the same logic as the one in the converse of the theorem above, wouldn't that mean that the sequence of functions need not to be uniformly convergent?

I am not quite sure about this though. What are some examples or information that is relevant?

Comment: Also, this is a vague question. Let me know how to correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f_n = 1_{[n,\infty)}$ (that is $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \ge n\\0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$).

Then $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x$, but $f_n$ does not converge to 0 uniformly.

Another example, let $g_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\
x^n, & x \in [0,1]\\1, & x > 1 \end{cases}$. Then $g_n(x) \to g(x)$, where
$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 1 \\1, & x \ge 1 \end{cases}$, which is not continuous. Furthermore, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand the function. Isn't $f_n$ just equal to a constant function?

Comment: No. I have elaborated the definition slightly.

Comment: Is the $x\geq n$ condition for the $1$ or the $0$?

Comment: It is for the 1.

Comment: So when you say $0$ otherwise, do you mean that $f_{1000}(x)=0$ if $x=999$? I am not really familiar with this notation.

Comment: Fix $x$. Then if $n \le x$ we have $f_n(x) = 1$, if $n >x$, we have $f_n(x) = 0$. So, in your example, $f_{1000}(999) = 0$, since $1000>999$.

Comment: This sequence of functions converges uniformly to the zero function *on an interval* of $\Bbb R$---namely on any interval with finite upper bound. So I can't see how it serves as a counterexample to the implication posed by the OP.

Comment: @JohnBentin: Some people take an interval to be a convex set in $\mathbb{R}$, which includes $\mathbb{R}$. In any case, the $g_n$ converge pointwise to $g$ which is discontinuous and the convergence is necessarily not uniform on any interval containing $(1-\epsilon,1]$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the claim is false: there are sequences of continuous functions that converge to nowhere-continuous functions. An explicit way to do this is to construct a sequence of continuous functions that converge to $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$, the function which is $1$ on the rationals and zero otherwise.

What *is* true, however, is a related idea called [Egorov's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem).